# create a dataframe of structtype/printschema results of two pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark, compare, schema, dtype

I have two spark dataframes that I would like to compare the data types but I would like to compare them side by side, which I intend to have them in a dataframe containing the schema of both:

```
df1.printSchema()
```

returns

```
root
 |-- orgID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deptID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- systemID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- autoID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- personID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeFirst: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeMiddle: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeLast: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeDOB: string (nullable = true)
```

```
df2.printSchema()
```

returns

```
root
 |-- orgID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- deptID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- systemID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- eventType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- autoID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- personID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeFirst: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeMiddle: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeLast: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employeeDOB: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

I would like to have a dataframe of the two together, to create another column that compares df1type vs df2type ['True', 'False']

```
+-------------+----------+---------+
|       column|   df1type|  df2type|
+-------------+----------+---------+
|        orgID|    string|  integer|
|       deptID|    string|   string|
...
|  employeeDOB|    string|timestamp|
+-------------+----------+---------+
```

so far, what I can tell from the following:

```
df1.schema == df2.schema
```

that the two dataframes are not equal. Above will return `False`

I tried converting each printSchema into a table, and merge later, but putting a printSchema() result is challenging, i think.

I need to find out which common columns have different structTypes. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: easiest would be to loop over the schemas and compare each element

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's it, but try this.

```py
df2.except(df1)
```

Comment: I am not sure this would work. I am not comparing the values in each column, but the column names/headers itself. Do you know how to convert the printSchema results into a spark dataframe? then I think I can use the except function.